# How to select appender for log4net?

Tags: c#, log4net

Nhibernate is setup using log4net, and is currently logging to the console. **and I want it to keep it this way.**

I am now adding a fileappender.  So in my code, how to I create a new logger class and make sure it uses this fileappender?

Again, I want nhibernate to continue to use whatever I had before, here is my original config:

```
<log4net debug="false">
    <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender, log4net">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default priority -->
    <root>
      <priority value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your fileAppender to the config file and add a reference to it inside the root node after the console one and both appenders will be active and working at the same time. Assuming that NHibernate is reading and using that config file of course.

Comment: but how to choose one or the other in my code to write to the correct appender?